# Seven segment detection using a webcam in Phyton

Tags: detection, seven-segment-display

So I wrote a program in Phyton to detect numbers displayed in seven segment display using my webcam. The code gets executed without any errors but when I put numbers in front of the webcam the program doesn't detect them.

I'll show my programming here and I hope someone can help me woth my issue.

```
import cv2
from djitellopy import tello
from segments import Segments

Thres = 0.6
nmsThres = 0.2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # 0 for default camera, adjust accordingly
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)



#drone = tello.Tello()
#drone.connect()
#print(drone.get_battery())
#drone.streamoff()
#drone.streamon()
#drone.takeoff()

segment_processor = Segments()


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    #img = drone.get_frame_read().frame
    try:
        segment_processor.digest(img)

        # Get the recognized digit
        recognized_digit = segment_processor.getNum()

        # Draw bounding box and display recognized digit on the output
        if recognized_digit != -1:
            h, w, _ = img.shape
            cv2.rectangle(img, (10, 10), (w - 10, h - 10), (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Bounding box around the whole image
            cv2.putText(img, f"Detected Digit: {recognized_digit}", (20, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0),
                        2)

        # Print or use the recognized digit as needed
        print("Recognized Digit:", recognized_digit)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        pass

    except:
        pass
    #dorne.send_rc_control(0,0,0,0)
    cv2.imshow("image",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And the segments iam using are the following:
import numpy as np

```
class Segments:
    def __init__(self):
        # create a 7seg model
        self.flags = []
        self.segments = []
        h1 = [[0, 1.0], [0, 0.1]]       # 0
        h2 = [[0, 1.0], [0.45, 0.55]]   # 1
        h3 = [[0, 1.0], [0.9, 1.0]]     # 2
        vl1 = [[0, 0.2], [0, 0.5]]      # 3 # upper-left
        vl2 = [[0, 0.2], [0.5, 1.0]]    # 4
        vr1 = [[0.8, 1.0], [0, 0.5]]    # 5 # upper-right
        vr2 = [[0.8, 1.0], [0.5, 1.0]]  # 6
        self.segments.append(h1)
        self.segments.append(h2)
        self.segments.append(h3)
        self.segments.append(vl1)
        self.segments.append(vl2)
        self.segments.append(vr1)
        self.segments.append(vr2)

    # process an image and set flags
    def digest(self, number):
        # reset flags
        self.flags = []

        # check res to see if it's a one
        h, w = number.shape[:2]
        if w < 0.5 * h:
            self.flags.append(5)
            self.flags.append(6)
            return

        # check for segments
        for a in range(len(self.segments)):
            seg = self.segments[a]
            # get bounds
            xl, xh = seg[0]
            yl, yh = seg[1]
            # convert to pix coords
            xl = int(xl * w)
            xh = int(xh * w)
            yl = int(yl * h)
            yh = int(yh * h)
            sw = xh - xl
            sh = yh - yl
            # check
            count = np.count_nonzero(number[yl:yh, xl:xh] == 255)
            print(f"Segment {a}: Count {count}, Total Pixels {sh * sw}, Percentage {count / (sh * sw)}")
            if count / (sh * sw) > 0.2:  # 0.5 is a sensitivity measure
                self.flags.append(a)

    # returns the stored number (stored in self.flags)
    def getNum(self):
        # hardcoding outputs
        if self.flags == [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
            return 0
        if self.flags == [5, 6]:
            return 1
        if self.flags == [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]:
            return 2
        if self.flags == [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]:
            return 3
        if self.flags == [1, 3, 5, 6]:
            return 4
        if self.flags == [0, 1, 2, 3, 6]:
            return 5
        if self.flags == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]:
            return 6
        if self.flags == [0, 5, 6]:
            return 7
        if self.flags == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
            return 8
        if self.flags == [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]:
            return 9
        # ERROR
        return -1
```

I have tried changing the threshold and using different kinds of seven segment display in black and in red but nothing changed.